# How am I still being tracked

Tags: firefox, proxy, privacy, tor

I recently switched to using the TOR browser, in addition I periodically do a complete history delete (cookies, cache, etc).  Incidentally I also have Adblock installed for the TOR browser.  However I am *still* getting Taboola Sponsored articles in TOR on sites like Drudge, etc that dovetail with various specific searches I've done (within TOR)  and its extremely disconcerting  and I don't understand how its still being done.  For example,  I was doing a  search just two days ago in TOR for "Kriptonite" (was brainstorming for names for an encryption product, but not relevant).  Well just now in Drudge, one of their sponsored ads was about Superman.  I know for a fact its related to that search I did,  and I get the same sort of "sponsored" articles for other searches I do as well.

As far as TOR,  I do have NoScript disabled, but only because disabling Javscript is a nonstarter these days, I might as well abandon the web if abandoning JS.  But, If I am pretty often completely deleting my history, what do they have to track me on.  I can delete my history right now in TOR, and also establish a new TOR identity, and if I go back into Drudge that same stupid sponsored article for Superman will be up, mocking me.  How am I still being tracked (Note: I usually use the TOR default search engine StartPage, but also Google occasionally.)

Comment: https://panopticlick.eff.org/

Comment: Thanks Oliver, I will do their check in a minute here.  But what is the solution -- to overwrite identifiable info with random data in every http request my computer sends out?

Answer (score 3):

To avoid being identifiable, you need a plain installation of your operating system. This is to minimize the risk of you having a unique combination of the things Panopticlick uses.

Then, you’d have to rollback everything to the vanilla state after every shutdown. You’d make an exception for installing updates, but you must not surf the Internet while doing so. This is to prevent things like [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) from taking root. It uses the following methods (list taken from linked page) to work around cookie clearing:

- Standard HTTP Cookies
- Local Shared Objects (Flash Cookies)
- Silverlight Isolated Storage
- Storing cookies in RGB values of auto-generated, force-cached 
  PNGs using HTML5 Canvas tag to read pixels (cookies) back out
- Storing cookies in Web History
- Storing cookies in HTTP ETags
- Storing cookies in Web cache
- window.name caching
- Internet Explorer userData storage
- HTML5 Session Storage
- HTML5 Local Storage
- HTML5 Global Storage
- HTML5 Database Storage via SQLite
- HTML5 IndexedDB
- Java JNLP PersistenceService
- Java CVE-2013-0422 exploit (applet sandbox escaping)

Comment: Would upvote this, but don't have enough  credentials yet, thanks.  Good laundry list to review.  Also evercookie -- will google that.  Would have thought and hoped that TOR would take care of cleaning out say HTML5 Session and Local Storage, etc. maybe it does.  I know that even without cookies, unique javascript files can be downloaded to identify a user subsequently, but again, cleaning the cache would presumably handle that.

Comment: TOR hides your IP. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I think it does a good bit more than that -- StartPage, NoScript, httpseverywhere, etc -- its a whole suite of things.  On a side note, if you use Google in TOR, Google hates it,  and keeps on making you pass primitive captcha tests, (They don't even use their new NoCaptcha for some reason)  which I can't figure out, as surely Google doesn't need your IP to know who you are.

Comment: Well, no. That’s not TOR. TOR is just that: Traffic routing. Everything else are separate and independent programs/add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the FF Add-On Random Agent Spoofer in TOR, and selected every single option it has, just a whole litany of things it does to disable any possibility of evercookie/supercookies, or browser fingerprinting, e.g.disabling local DOM storage, disabling plugin enumeration, disabling canvas, random periodic changes to user agent, disabling system fonts, and on and on, must be 100 different things you can activate and I selected them all, *IN TOR*.  I even wrote my own custom add-on to intercept requests going out and change some other headers so that panopticlick gave me a better score.

The net result: nothing.  In TOR, on say, rt.com,  I *still* get a couple of rows of taboola-sponsored articles correlating to specific web activity of mine over the last couple of months.  And the crazy thing is,  I have no such problem in straight Firefox.  Even without Random Agent Spoofer etc,  *I am not* getting taboola articles like that in straight Firefox correlating to my web activity.  I get some other default taboola articles, basically the same ones over and over that have nothing to do with me.  So, it seems like to me TOR is a scam run by the NSA or whomever, but a scam one way or the other. Not in any sense a replacement for a vpn.

So the answer is, there is no answer when it comes to TOR.

On a slightly different note, on my smart phone I get google ads correlating to either shows I've watched repeatedly on Verizon, OR, stuff its picking up in my room through the mike in my smartphone.  One of those two things it is doing.  Does that come as a surprise to anyone?  Does everyone but me already know they're doing this?

Comment: Btw, I also have Ghostery installed on TOR.

Comment: In actuality, what I described above about using Random Agent Spoofer, etc was only the tip of the iceberg of countermeasures I took to defeat whatever was tracking me in TOR.  For example, I also started periodically releasing and renewing the IP in my Verizon router, i.e.  basically getting a new IP every day or so, and did a whole gamut of other things in the verizon router, that was all in addition to what's described above.  I am still getting tracked by Taboola in TOR specifically!